# make td element invisible or its inner html blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an element like this.

```
 <td id = "reconText" style='vertical-align:bottom;font-weight:bold;'></td>
```

I have a javascript function that does something else:

```
 if (!showReconText) 
  var obj = document.getElementById("reconText");
  obj.innerHTML = " ";
```

It works for me but I am looking for a more elegant solution such as can I hide the td element altogether instead of " " or is there something like String.Empty in javascript/Jquery.

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question: I would consider setting a class to reconText cells rather than using inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

Hiding a solitary TD element can be dodgy work; you could wrap "hiding" candidates in a span or something, and then call `.hide()` (jQuery) on the span. If you try to hide a TD by setting display to none or by removing it, you will break the table's flow.

If you don't need the cell's contents ever again, just emptying the string as described in other responses (or with your own JS sample) is fine. If you potentially need to "reveal" it again with another function, consider the 'wrapping in another element' strategy.

Answer (score 0):

try `document.getElementById("reconText").style.display = 'none';`

Answer (score 0):

```
//if u want to hide
$("td#reconText").hide();

//if u want to remove
$("td#reconText").remove();
```

Comment: This answer and other posts that you have made uses a lot of text speak. Please don't. [Start reading here if you have any questions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105497).